# Controlling multiple TRIACs using one optoisolator

Tags: opto-isolator, triac

I was wondering if it's possible to control multiple TRIACs using only a single Optoisolator.

All the loads are resistive.

here is the schematic of what I am trying to achieve.

I have tried to do some research, but so far I could not find anything that would indicate that this is possible/bad or not.

Another question, what if the three loads are (almost) identical, would that be different if they are not?

[image]

Update #1: I know that this can be done using only a single TRIAC, however I have so many small 0.6A TRIACS and the loads are very small <0.3A.

Comment: Why 3 TRIACs at all?

Comment: Good question, I guess this is more curiosity than a practical application.
And because I am not sure how to analyze the behavior of the circuit in this case.

Comment: This would be very unreliable. Even if you give each TRIAC its own gate resistor, if Q7 turns on first, the trigger energy is gone.

Comment: That's interesting, I did not know that; my thinking was that since they are in parallel then then would all get the same current (I could also use a smaller resistor).

Comment: With "trigger energy gone" I wanted to say, that there is no longer enough voltage at pin 6 of the coupler because Q7 is conducting. From all gates receiving the same voltage you cannot conclude, that the currents or the time to trigger are the same. Little variations in the manufacturing process or temperature have a large impact.

Comment: @MohamedEl-Sayed Things in *series* get the same current; things in parallel get the same *voltage*.

Comment: So this is similar in principle to how BJTs can not be connected in parallel (because they are current controlled) while MOSFETs can(because they are voltage controlled), right?

Comment: why are you switching neutral?

Answer (score 0):

it should be possible but I think you need to flip the triacs around so that T2 connects to the common.

Then when the first triac turns on it will pull it's gate to the common ensuring that all the other triacs also turn on.

This  arrangement is only going to work for passive loads, any load that can generate an emf or a phase shift past zero crossing will be able to turn the triacs on or prevent them from turning off.